# Seq2Seq Model - Chatbot

Tags: user-interface, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot using `seq2seq`. Normally we remove all punctuation and stop words while processing of Text Data and feed the same to `Model`.

So my questions will this not impact the readability of `Output`?
For example - a user input some question in Chatbot window and press enter to get an answer. Now if the user gets the answer without the punctuation and stop words,  will this impact the readability?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what type of *Chatbot* you want to create. Generally we have two types of *ChatBots*:

- **Retrieval-based**: You train your model with lots of pairs. In inference phase, your model find most similar item to training example and return to that to the user. In this case, we find most similar item between user question and our questions. Then return to most similar question's response to the user. So if we do preprocessing, on question this will not affect the readability or other things.
- **Generation-based**: In generation based chatbot (Such as `seq2seq` that you mentioned), the response of the chatbot is completely rely on what you feed in for training. If you remove punctuation or stop-word, Yes it impact on your response and you can not see those things in your *Chatbot* response.

Answer (score 0):

Of *course* it degrades readability.  Many of those words and all of the punctuation exist to guide the reader to the intended parsing of the sentence.  To put it another way:

```
course degrades readability many words
punctuation guide reader intended parsing 
sentence put another way
```

There are many examples of phrases, sentences, and paragraphs that *require* punctuation to disambiguate the intended meaning.

Removal of "syntactic sugar" is *only* to promote using certain (most) techniques for quickly determining likely relevance to a similarly processed document.  Your bot design has to separate this process from the user interface.  Whatever you return to the user should be in human language, not the internal word soup you employ for information retrieval.